# hdfs-sink: how to get rid of the timestamp added in every event by flume in the HDFS files

Tags: flume-ng

I have a few files which contains json in each line

```
[root@ip-172-29-1-12 vp_flume]# more vp_170801.txt.finished | awk '{printf("%s\n", substr($0,0,20))}'
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
{"status":"OK","resp
```

My flume config is

```
[root@ip-172-29-1-12 flume]# cat flume_test.conf 
agent.sources = seqGenSrc
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = loggerSink

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type = spooldir
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.spoolDir = /moveitdata/dong/vp_flume
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.deserializer.maxLineLength = 10000000
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.fileSuffix = .finished
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.deletePolicy = never

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100

agent.sinks.loggerSink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.path = /home/dong/vp_flume

agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.rollSize = 1000000000
agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.rollCount = 0
```

The files in HDFS is:

```
[root@ip-172-29-1-12 flume]# hadoop fs -text /home/dong/vp_flume/* | awk '{printf("%s\n", substr($0,0,20))}' | more
1505276698665   {"stat
1505276698665   {"stat
1505276698666   {"stat
1505276698666   {"stat
1505276698666   {"stat
1505276698667   {"stat
1505276698667   {"stat
1505276698667   {"stat
1505276698668   {"stat
1505276698668   {"stat
1505276698668   {"stat
1505276698668   {"stat
1505276698669   {"stat
1505276698669   {"stat
1505276698669   {"stat
1505276698669   {"stat
1505276698670   {"stat
1505276698670   {"stat
1505276698670   {"stat
1505276698670   {"stat
```

Question: I don't like the timestamp which is added by flume in each event. However, how can I get rid of it by configuring flume properly?

Answer (score 1):

You have not explicitly mentioned a `hdfs.fileType` property in your agent config file so Flume will use `SequenceFile` as default. SequenceFile supports two write formats: `Text` and `Writable`. You have set `hdfs.writeFormat = Text` which means Flume will use `HDFSTextSerializer` to serialize your events. If you take a look at [its source](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/dfa0627573b9a75a25dc7149a7d63c9bac953ff4/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSTextSerializer.java#L53) (Line 53), you will see that it adds a timestamp as the default key.

Using `hdfs.writeFormat = Writable` won't help either because it does the same. You can check its source [here](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/dfa0627573b9a75a25dc7149a7d63c9bac953ff4/flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hdfs/HDFSWritableSerializer.java#L52) (Line 52).

A key is always required for a [SequenceFile](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile). So, unless you have a good reason to use `SequenceFile` I'd suggest you to use `hdfs.fileType = DataStream` in your agent config.